# Passing an Object to a method and returning a list of Objects any example

Tags: java

Friends
 Im posting my question again as previous question was unclear . 
I want to pass an object of an class who's member variables are string , Listof A String and a List of an class member variable to a method that copies the contents of above class objects and returns a Lsit of class object which can be used by an java method.
Any example will be nice

Now I have  a

Comment: Where's the class definition for `CallFlowResource`?

Comment: _all the values of CallFlowObject obj_ What do you mean? Its fields? Those aren't of type `CallFlowResource`.

Comment: Why are you making calls to `super()` when you're only inheriting from `Object`?

Comment: Where is 'CallFlowResource'?

Comment: @HenryKeiter: auto-generated code...

Comment: `CallFlowResource` is not a parent of `CallFlowObject` or any of it's member fields. Therefore it is opaque what you're actually attempting to do here.

Comment: CallFlowResource is another class which is a return type of the method that accepts CallFlowObject ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is the class for CallFlowResource??
A simple way would be for you to create a list and add the values as you want them to be outputted.

It you would look like this:

```
public List<CallFlowResource> getCallFlow(CallFlowObject obj)
{
   List<CallFlowResource> callFlowRes = new ArrayList<>();
   for(int i = 0; i<size; i++)
   {
       callFlowRes.add(obj.GetterMethodForCFR(i));
   }
   return callFlowRes;
}
```

Comment: how about copying the List<CallStep> callSteps,
                              List<String> audioRefs to the obj of CallFlowResource provided that it has another List of CallStep

Comment: Im raising a new question with all required details

Comment: I can't seem to understand what you mean, the output is a List of type CallFlowResource, you can put anything you want as long as its of that type